# Packages installed by mini.iso Ubuntu image

Tags: ubuntu-minimal

I would like to get some information about mini.iso Ubuntu images mentioned in this link:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

What are the packages that this image installs by default?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The minimal image will prompt you to select software. It depends on what you select

Comment: As stated in the page linked, the mini.iso, connects to the internet and downloads the files from the Ubuntu repositories. I believe this was also called a "net Installer". The term "minimal" refers to the installer size, not any difference in the installed OS. ie it will install a full system, plus your selected desktop if any. If the kernel supports your network connection, only two files are required to do a network install.